# How to show different textbox depending on which radio button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I am working with JSP and I have a html form in which I have a button at the top which is Process button. Now if I click on that Process button, it shows me a form which has two radio button - `TestClient` and `TestServer`.

It also has `Submit` button in that form.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmqk/36/)

**Problem Statement:-**

Now what I am trying to do is -  As soon as I click on `TestClient` radio button, I would like to show two text box and one radio button along with label just below that `TestClient` and `TestServer` like this -

```
TestClient      TestServer

Name    textbox
Id      textbox
Sex     Male    Female

Submit button
```

In the same way if I am clicking `TestServer` button - I would like to show three text box and one drop down menu just below the `TestClient` and `TestServer`

```
TestClient      TestServer

Address         textbox
ClientId        textbox
ServerId        textbox
Country         dropdownbox

Submit button
```

Is this possible to do using jquery in my current jsfiddle example? If yes, then any jsfiddle example will be of great help to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Very do-able.](http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmqk/37/) I've just added a quick example with a div for each radio button and some text in them. You can add your own inputs etc.

Hide these divs with CSS by default.

```
<div class="client" style="display: none">
    Client fields here
</div>

<div class="server" style="display: none">
    Server fields here
</div>
```

Then you can do something like this with your jQuery handler:

```
$('input[name="client"]').click(function() {
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'client') {
        $('.client').show();
        $('.server').hide();
    } else {
        $('.client').hide();
        $('.server').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to code the html and show/hide it, but you prefere to generate it with jquery, you can also use this solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/fauv9/1/

```
<button id="primary">Process</button>
<form method='post'>
  <h4>Process</h4>
    <fieldset><legend>process</legend>
      <input  id="client" value="TestClient"type="radio" name="cli_srv">
      <label for="client">TestClient</label>
      <input  id="server" value="TestServer" type="radio" name="cli_srv">
      <label for="server">TestServer</label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="form_process">
    </fieldset>
</form>
    <button form="form_process">Submit</button>
```

and

```
$("#primary").click(function(){
    $("form").show()
});

var form= $('#form_process');

$("#client").click(function(){
    form.html(null);
    form.append('<label for="cli_name">name</label><input value="name" id="cli_name"><br>')
    form.append('<label for="cli_id">id</label><input value="id" id="cli_id"><br>')
// etc...
})

$("#server").click(function(){
    form.html(null);
    form.append('<label for="cli_name">address</label><input value="address" id="address"><br>')
    form.append('<label for="srv_id">id</label><input value=" server id" id="srv_id"><br>')
// etc...
})
```